# create a delay between the running of functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery delay between animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951528/jquery-delay-between-animations)

I have created two functions:  One that animates an object from Point A to Point B, and the second, that animates from Point B to C.  I would like to have a time delay betweeen the 2 functions.
Can someone please tell me how to achieve this.  My unsuccessful attempt was:

```
movt_1().delay(5000).movt_2();
```

Also, I would like to have a delay right at the beginning BEFORE the first animation runs

Thanks!

Comment: If you do a search for [jQuery delay between animations](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+delay+between+animations), you'll get literally dozens of questions similar to or identical to this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function movt_1 ()
{
  //your code here
  setTimeout (movt_2, 5000);
}

function movt_2 ()
{
  //your code here
}

setTimeout (movt_1, 5000);
```

EDIT: Changed the first parameter to the "proper" way.

Comment: That should be `setTimeout(movt_1, 5000);` and `setTimeout(movt_2, 5000);`

Comment: Not sure, but w3cschool says different: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Comment: +1 to @qertymk, I've used it before and you don't have to put the double quotes and the parentheses.

Comment: Great, so both statements are equivalent.

Comment: @Hyperboreus: That site isn't the authoritative place for javascript. Check out http://w3fools.com/ to see what I mean

Comment: I am not firm on javascript. So my code won't work?

Comment: It will but it's not the proper way to do it for many reasons

Answer (score 3):

the jQuery .delay() function only works for functions that use the queue. For example, according to the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/delay/), the parameterless .show() and .hide() will not work. If you are using a function you wrote, you can use the [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) javascript function instead.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's .delay() function only works with items in the animation queue.

The example below uses .delay() and a callback function to modify the 2nd element:

```
$('#test1').hide('fade', {}, 1000).delay(3000).hide(0, function() {
    $('#test2').show(0).delay(3000).hide();
});
```